# flutter google services plug in

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, google-play-services, flutter-dependencies

Ok so I'm currently working on a Project in Android Studio using Flutter (I'm new to the Program) I ran the program to pick up errors a debug and I came across an error stating it couldn't pick up the google-services plugin and when I copy and paste the google doc that I had downloaded from firebase it had come up in this format:

```
o[D��b
o[D��7                     � P�O� �:i�� +00� /C:\                   x 1     kQ�q Users d      �sN�$kQ�q.    t                :     o:� U s e r s   @ s h e l l 3 2 . d l l , - 2 1 8 1 3    P 1     5R�k Cathe <      ��P��5R�k.   �-                  �k C a t h e    � 1     >R�� DOWNLO~1  l       �sNJW>R��.   �-            B     fL- D o w n l o a d s   @ s h e l l 3 2 . d l l , - 2 1 7 9 8    ~ 2 7  >R��  GO1CA4~1.JSO  b      �>R��>R��.   wZ                  ��  g o o g l e - s e r v i c e s   ( 6 ) . j s o n      `            -       _         gZ
,    C:\Users\Cathe\Downloads\google-services (6).json  ( . . \ . . \ D o w n l o a d s \ g o o g l e - s e r v i c e s   ( 6 ) . j s o n  C : \ U s e r s \ C a t h e \ D o w n l o a d s      �����y       ���M7
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Where you storing `google-services.json` file?

Comment: i copy and paste the file into the flutter project under the app file .. but for storing the file its on my desktop

Comment: And file named `google-services.json`? Not `google-services (6).json`?

Comment: google-services (6).json it is named

Comment: Rename it to `google-services.json`. `google-services (6).json` is not valid name for Google Services config.

Comment: ok is that why its coming up with odd format as stated above?

Comment: Odd format? What are you mean?

Comment: the format as i stated above in the question

Comment: Maybe in your `Downloads` folder on PC contains more that one files that name starts with `google-services.json`. If you download files with the same name Windows by default doesn't delete old file, it just create a new and add number to it's name.